# Calculated Column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, calculated-columns

I have my data in table as:

```
id  Author_ID   Research_Area       Category_ID  Paper_Count   Paper_Year   Rank  
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   677         feature extraction  8            1             2005         1
2   677         image annotation    11           1             2005         2
3   677         probabilistic model 12           1             2005         3
4   677         semantic            19           1             2007         1
5   677         feature extraction  8            1             2009         1
6   677         image annotation    11           1             2011         1  
7   677         semantic            19           1             2012         1  
8   677         video sequence      5            2             2013         1  
9   1359        adversary model     1            2             2005         1
10  1359        ensemble method     14           2             2005         2
11  1359        image represent     11           2             2005         3
12  1359        adversary model     1            7             2006         1
13  1359        concurrency control 17           5             2006         2
14  1359        information system  12           2             2006         3  
15  ...         
16  ...
```

Whereas I want to have an output of query as:

```
id  Author_ID   Category_ID  Paper_Count   Category_Prob   Paper_Year   Rank  
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   677         8            1             0.333           2005         1
2   677         11           1             0.333           2005         2
3   677         12           1             0.333           2005         3
4   677         19           1             1.0             2007         1
5   677         8            1             1.0             2009         1
6   677         11           1             1.0             2011         1  
7   677         19           1             1.0             2012         1  
8   677         5            2             1.0             2013         1  
9   1359        1            2             0.333           2005         1
10  1359        14           2             0.333           2005         2
11  1359        11           2             0.333           2005         3
12  1359        1            7             0.5             2006         1
13  1359        17           5             0.357           2006         2
14  1359        12           2             0.142           2006         3  
15  ...         
16  ...
```

Whereas `Category_Prob` is a calculated column which is calculated in two steps as:

*Step First*, we have to have a `SUM` of `Paper_Count` in each `Paper_Year` for instance i.e. `Paper_Year = 2005` and `Author_ID = 677`, the `SUM(Paper_Count) = 3`

*Step Second*, then for each `Category_ID`, we have to divide `Paper_Count` with value of `SUM(Paper_Count)` in that `Paper_Year` which will be `1/3` i.e. `0.333` and so on...

Moreover, I have tried this query:

```
SELECT 
    Author_ID, Abstract_Category, Paper_Count,
    [Category_Prob] = Paper_Count / SUM(Paper_Count),
    Paper_Year, Rank
FROM 
    Author_Areas
GROUP BY 
    Author_ID, Abstract_Category, Paper_Year, Paper_Count, Rank
ORDER BY 
    Author_ID, Paper_Year
```

But it returns just `1` in the column `Category_Prob` for all of the rows in the table.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem with your query is that you are not grouping by `Paper_Year`, but also by `Author_ID, Abstract_Category, Paper_Count, Rank`. Hence `SUM(Paper_Count)` is equal to Paper_Count for each group.

You can use `SUM OVER` for this:

```
SELECT      id, Author_ID, Abstract_Category [Category_ID],  
            Paper_Count, 
            Paper_Count * 1.0 / SUM(Paper_Count)  
            OVER (PARTITION BY Author_ID, Paper_Year) AS [Category_Prob],
            Paper_Year, Rank
FROM        Author_Areas
ORDER BY    Author_ID, Paper_Year
```

**Note:** You have to multiply by `1.0` so as to avoid integer division.
**Note 2:** Perhaps you have to add `Author_ID` field in the `PARTITION BY` clause as well, if your actual requirement is to group by author, year.

Comment: @Giorgos--The query executed successfully but values in the `calculated_column` are not as desired

Comment: @Bridge I think not. `SUM` with `OVER` clause is available from SQL Server 2005 onwards (not 100% sure though). Sql Server 2012 added the `ORDER BY` in the `OVER` clause so as to calculate running totals.

Comment: @maliks What results do you get?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos Oh yeah! I just added `(PARTITION BY Author_ID, Paper_Year)` and I got desired results. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect (please confirm) that the datatype of all fields involved are `integers`. When you calculate with `int` the return type is also `int`. You should `convert` the fields to `decimal` before calculation.

```
SELECT Author_ID, Abstract_Category, Paper_Count,
[Category_Prob] = convert(decimal(10,3), Paper_Count) / convert(decimal(10, 3), SUM(Paper_Count)),
Paper_Year, Rank
FROM Author_Areas
GROUP BY Author_ID, Abstract_Category, Paper_Year, Paper_Count, Rank
ORDER BY Author_ID, Paper_Year
```